# Network manager opened by itself

Tags: networking, network-manager, security, remote, remote-access

I left my computer on overnight because it had some updates to install, and I didn't feel like waiting for it to reboot just to shut it down. However, when I logged back in this morning, the network manager was open and it was displaying all the information for my wifi network.

Anyone know why it happened? Or was someone remotely accessing my computer?

Comment: Reboot or a shutdown will do the same thing, if you want to shutdown after updates, shutdown instead of rebooting.

Comment: Updates usually only take a minute or two to complete(unless it has been a long time) and most do not need a reboot.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the rebooting for updates. I was asking why my Network Manager was already open to my router settings when I logged in.